# Hibernate - child removed but parent is not

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

i have two entites:

```
public class Branch extends IdModel {

   @Column(nullable = false)
   private Boolean warehouse;

   @OneToOne(optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "delivery_address", nullable = false, orphanRemoval = true)
   private DeliveryAddress deliveryAddress;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "company", nullable = false)
   private Company company;

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "additionalBranches")
   private List<User> otherUsers = new ArrayList<>();

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "homeBranch", orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<User> homeUsers = new ArrayList<>();

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "branch", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
   private List<BroadcastRule> broadcastRules = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and

```
public class DeliveryAddress extends IdModel {

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "owner_company", nullable = false)
   private Company ownerCompany;


   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "deliveryAddress")
   private Branch branch;

   .
   .
   .
```

}

And i am using Spring's JpaRepository delete(T entity) method to delete a Branch. All it does is bunch of select queries, deletes broadcast rules (if any present), but does not remove the Branch entity itself - the delete SQL query is not sent to DB. I tried to remove the Branch entity directly using a native query, but that just resulted in constraint violation because deliveryAddress is still referencing the Branch. I want to avoid removing all the related stuff manually and would like to have Hibernate to do the work for me.

How can i make hibernate to actually remove the Branch entity and THEN remove the delivery addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. "Company" entity which has a collection of Branches had the fetch type set to eager, changing it to lazy did the trick